# how to change clickable item when i click them in JqueryMobile?

Tags: css, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am developing a task in using phonegap and jquerymobile.

How should i do to change the color of a clickable item when i click on them? 
I have written the code below:

```
 $(".testbutton").click(function(){
    $(".testbutton").css("background-color","yellow");
    });
```

But the background color will only change yellow after i release my mouse on it. I wan it to change to yellow whenever my mouse is clicked on tat item, and recover to its original background color when i release the mouse.

Can anyone please help?

Comment: I have found a similar problem that other ppl meet:

I'm doing a game using PhoneGap for iPhone. Everything was going swimmingly until I tried a mousedown event. Works correctly in PC and Mac versions of Safari, but no event occurs until the user pulls a finger up when using the iPhone's Safari.
Current solution is to move from jQuery's "mousedown" to XUI library's "touchstart" event.
Another concern with jQuery is that it's large compared to XUI. Much
of that is due to jQuery's smoothing out of IE's quirks.
Any thoughts of a tuned version of jQuery for mobile, or specifically for iPhone?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're trying to accomplish?

Live Example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/A2bd3/16/

CSS:

```
.task-bg-color {
    background-color: yellow;   
}
```

JS:

```
$('#clickAndHold').mousedown(function() {
    $(this).children().addClass('task-bg-color');
    $('ul#tasks').listview('refresh');
});

$('#clickAndHold').mouseup(function() {
    $(this).children().removeClass('task-bg-color');
    $('ul#tasks').listview('refresh');
});

$('#clickAndStick').click(function() {
    $(this).children().addClass('task-bg-color');
    $('ul#tasks').listview('refresh');
});

$('#clickAndToggle').click(function() {
    if ($(this).children().hasClass('task-bg-color')) {
        $(this).children().removeClass('task-bg-color');
    } else {
        $(this).children().addClass('task-bg-color');
    }
    $('ul#tasks').listview('refresh');
});
```

HTML:

```
<div data-role="page" class="type-home">
    <div data-role="content">
        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="c" data-dividertheme="f" id="tasks">
            <li data-role="list-divider">Tasks (Background actions)</li>
            <li id="clickAndHold"><a href="#">Click &amp; Hold</a></li>
            <li id="clickAndStick"><a href="#">Click &amp; Stick</a></li>
            <li id="clickAndToggle"><a href="#">Click &amp; Toggle</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```